# How to turn a recorded Macro to an automated Macro in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have recorded the following macro to sort data in the range "B3:U47" based on the values of the column "C3:C47".

```
Sub Sorting_Finance()
    Range("B3:U47").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Finance").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Finance").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("C3:C47"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Finance").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B3:U47")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Every time I want to sort the data I press Control+n. Is there a way to do this automatically when I enter a new value in the column C? I am trying to change it through VBA, but no success till now.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
if not (intersect(target, Range("C3:C47")) is nothing) then 
    call Sorting_Finance
end if
end sub
```

And do not forget to remove/comment `Range("B3:U47").Select` line.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: @AlexSpanos do you get any errors? How doesn't it work?

Comment: @AlexSpanos Set breakpoint into the method. Trace the code. Find where is the problem.

Comment: @AlexSpanos is important to place this code in the code module of the sheet you want to sort, and not just in a general module (where your macro was recorded to)

Comment: @AlexSpanos is the new value in a row greater than 47? If so, this snippet will ignore the change and not call your `Sorting_Finance` routine. If you're _adding_ additional values you'll want `Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")` - that will pick up any changes anywhere in column `C`. This code, as written will only pick up changes in rows 3-47.

Comment: Also, pay attention to @MátéJuhász information - that's _critical_ to making this work.

Comment: Ok, I found what goes wrong. The matter is that the values of the column C are taken from another sheet. I tried the code in a simple example where i just change by myself the prices and it works. But when the prices are taken from another sheet, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Akina Is there a solution to this?